# How to run appveyor.yml script locally?

Tags: appveyor

I want to install mlpack in windows and I found the [appveyor.yml](https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/blob/master/.appveyor.yml) script in github. Instead of following and executing each step manually, is there a way to run this script in my laptop? Like, something similar to a bat file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`appveyor.yml`is configuration file for [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com) builds, and supposed to be executed on AppVeyor build VMs. I heard about project [LocalAppVeyor](https://github.com/joaope/LocalAppVeyor) which should help you to run this locally but I did not try it.

If you want just bat file, you can copy all commands from `install` and `build_script` to your bat file. Command with just `-` in the beginning are standard cmd commands. Command with just `- ps:` in the beginning are expected to run in PowerShell, however I do not see anything PowerShell specific in command is this file. Sure you need to remove `-` and `- ps:` to run them in bat file.

`artifacts`, `notifications` and other AppVeyor specific steps cannot be called from bat file, they require engine which understand this file, which is AppVeyor build or this [LocalAppVeyor](https://github.com/joaope/LocalAppVeyor) which again I never tested.